# Correlations between the pK values of acids or based in polar and non-polar solvents

Tags: physical-chemistry, solvents

I try to predict pKa values of acids (in water), computing their energy of deprotonation with quantum chemistry; and I found that the slope of the linear correlation "pK vs Energy" is more close to the theoretical value, if the computation uses an advanced method of computing the solvent effects. I try to explain this obsevation theoretically. Please comment, whether the following argumentation is correct:

Strong acids contain more polar OH fragments (in the neutral form), so strong acids in the neutral form are more strongly stabilized in polar solvents than in non-polar ones. As a result, in polar solvents, compared to non-polar solvents, strong acids become slightly weaker, and weak acids become slightly stronger.

Is this statement true? If we take a number of e.g. acids and measure their pKa in water and non-polar solvents, will it turn out that a polar solvent slightly reduces the dependence of pKa on the properties of the molecules themselves, i.e. in polar solvents, strong acids become a little weaker, and weak acids a little stronger due to the solvent?

In other words, I want to find a data on pK values of acids in non-polar solvents (or at least less polar than water), and check the correlation between the pKa values in water and in these solvents; the most important value is the slope of this correlation (whether it is not 1.0).

Comment: That's not true - afaik strong acids tend to be weaker in lower polarity solvents. More precisely, the effect you consider is present for some acids, but should be rather negligible.

Comment: And HCl solutions in toluene are not conducting electricity.

Comment: For analysing strength of acid, it's rather good to consider situation of ions after dissociation. Here comes solvent's dielectric constant, showing how well ions are "shielded" from each other

Comment: @Maurice Sure, but it only says it can't protonate toluene, if you added some methanol, this would change, I think.

Comment: @Mithoron can you provide some links for articles?

Comment: Articles about experimental data, or theoretical predictions? As far as values are concerned, you can just check pKa table with water vs DMSO values.

Comment: @Mithoron I thought I will not to have to build this correlation myself, or at least I will not have to google the pKa values for each compound manually. Maybe at least there are papers where these values are shown together at a table?

Comment: Well, I just told you about pKa tables, for example https://organicchemistrydata.org/hansreich/resources/pka/